# Telegram Bot Webhook Not Working on My Laravel and Let's Encrypt SSL

Tags: laravel, ssl, telegram, webhooks, lets-encrypt

I can get update via `getUpdates`but not with webhook.

Here is my route:

```
Route::post('/<MY BOT TOKEN>', function () {
Telegram::sendMessage([
    'chat_id' => "468613362",
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
    'text' => " Test message from webhook update, Hinbo Love you"
]);

return 'ok';
});
```

I did test the URL with Postman and it is returning "ok" as expected.

Excluded in VerifyCSRFToken.php:

```
 protected $except = [
    '/<MY BOT TOKEN>',
];
```

Webhook set by sending this request

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<MY BOT TOKEN>/setWebhook?url=https://lomba.ikarin.site/<MY BOT TOKEN>
```

and here is the response from telegram:

```
{
 ok: true,
 result: true,
 description: "Webhook was set"
}
```

My website is using let's encrypt ssl, my site: https://lomba.ikarin.site

I worried about the cert chain, so i checked `https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=lomba.ikarin.site` and it says

> Chain Issues: None

Worried about SSL/TLS version, so I contacted my shared hosting's support team and they said it is in version 1.2 as required.

what am I missing here?

Comment: What is the webhook status of your robot? (you can see it by calling `getWebhookInfo` function of the bot like [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getwebhookinfo) ).

Comment: @AliKhalili it says it is set, but connection time out

Answer (score 0):

`getUpdates` not working if you use webhook. try to use `Telegram::getWebhookUpdates();`